# Error when creating tableofcontents

Tags: table-of-contents

It gives me error when trying to create tableofcontent.The error is missing number treated as zero.Here is the code.

```
\documentclass[14pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[Rejne]{fncychap}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
............
.............

\end{titlepage}

\tableofcontents


\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Early life and education}
\cleardoublepage

\chapter{Career}
\section{2005 to 2010: Career beginnings, Kill Kill, and Lana Del Ray}
\section{2014: Ultraviolence}
\cleardoublepage

\chapter{Artistry}
\section{Musical style}
\section{Voice and timbre}
\section{Influences}


\chapter{Other ventures}
\section{Discography}
\section{Filmography}
\section{Awards and nominations}

\end{document}
```

any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: The problem is related with `\usepackage[Rejne]{fncychap}`. I'm looking for solution.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `\usepackage[Rejne]{fncychap}` is the cause of the problem... Oh, Sigur was faster than me ;-)

Comment: It runs with `scrbook` instead of `book`, but a look into the `fncychap.sty` file reveals a lot of deprecated `\bf` and `\rm` commands.

Comment: The easiest solution is not using `fncychap`; the quality of your document will immediately improve. `;-)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Rejne` option of the `fncychap` package is the cause of the problem. The real error is this:

```
! Use of \@icentercr doesn't match its definition.
```

The same error occurs if you use the `Conny` option, but not the `Sonny` option.
In `fncychap.sty`, both `Conny` and `Rejne` use `\centering` in their title commands, but `Sonny` does not.

So the package's use of `\centering` is inconsistent with its definition by the LaTeX core. This is a bug in the package, and you should notify the author.

The package author states:

> I have no idea if this package is written in a good way. Thus, if
>   anyone reads and tries *FncyChap* I would appreciate any feedback.

Comment: The whole package seems to be defined in a weird style, in my point of view

Comment: Thanks this actually solved the problem.I just used the Sonny option for the chapters and my table of contents showed up.:)

Comment: @goon Great! I would appreciate your upvote if you are so inclined. :) For what it's worth, I would probably not trust `fncychap` for a longer document, now that we know it has these fairly rudimentary errors. I might recommend instead using the `titlesec` package or the `memoir` class (among other options) for customizing your headers.

Comment: @AndrewCashner... You got some upvote (;-)) I agree with you, that there are perhaps better ways than `fncychap`, especially for the fact, that most of its code is about 15 years old.